# XPath error-->[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, dom, xpath, nodes

i wrote the below program, but when it goes ot the XPath classes it gives **[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.** i tried to figure it out but couldnt make it.is there any clue to fix this problem?

```
package xpath;

import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathVariableResolver;
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException;

public class XPath {
    private static int seg;

         private static void check(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
          if (node == null || node.getNodeName() == null)
    return;


  TFIDF( node.getNodeValue(),"java");
  check(node.getFirstChild());
if(node.getFirstChild()==null &&node.getNextSibling()==null)
     seg++;
System.out.println(node.getNodeValue() != null && node.getNodeValue().trim().length() == 0 ? "" : node);
    check(node.getNextSibling());
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {


             Parser p = new Parser();
        SAX2DOM sax2dom = null;
   org.w3c.dom.Node doc  = null;

       URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions");

   p.setFeature(Parser.namespacesFeature, false);
   p.setFeature(Parser.namespacePrefixesFeature, false);
   sax2dom = new SAX2DOM();
   p.setContentHandler(sax2dom);
   p.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())));
   doc = sax2dom.getDOM();

    Node html=doc.getFirstChild();
    check(html);

    }

    private static void TFIDF(String segment,  String keyword) throws XPathExpressionException {
  if (segment!=null)
  {
InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(segment));

    final String term = keyword;
String expression = "//*[contains(text(),$term)]";
final QName termVariableName = new QName("term");
class TermResolver implements XPathVariableResolver {
  @Override
  public Object resolveVariable(QName variableName) {
    return termVariableName.equals(variableName) ? term : null;
  }
}
        javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(new TermResolver());
Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, src, XPathConstants.NODE);

  }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Content is not allowed in prolog" error usually means that you have something before the first XML element in your document, often whitespace. Since you are grabbing `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`, I'd guess that it's the newline character after the `<!doctype>` that is causing the problem. According to the XML spec whitespace *should* be allowed in the prolog both before and after the doctype, but many tools do not handle this correctly.

Try manually removing the whitespace and see if that helps. If not, try removing the doctype declaration altogether.

Comment: `wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions` followed by `emacs questions` (or `vim` if you're a masochist ;)).

Comment: Download the source using a tool like wget or curl, then manually edit the content using your favourite text editor. Run the edited content through your program to see if that fixes the issue. If it does, then you know that your code will have to do some pre-processing before parsing the page.

Comment: isnt it easier i simply use **vie source** then copy paste the code in a text editor?

Comment: Sure, that should work too. Just make sure you copy & paste **everything**, including whitespace such as newline characters.

Comment: i mean simply using browser to see the code and get it like that

Comment: i did what you said, then it goes a little further then as soon as it reaches the **<title>** it gives error again. i looked at the code, it passed blank s[aces between tags so the new error(at least) wont be due to whitspace. it gave 3 new main errors: 1Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog. 2javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionExceptiont com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:476) 3org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.